# How do I link PyCharm to PyQt4?

Tags: pyqt4, pycharm

I use PyCharm 2016.2.3 (32-bit), Python 2.7.12 (32-bit), PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x32, Windows 7 Home Premium.

I would be grateful for the procedure to link PyCharm to PyQT4. I'm not a techie.

I linked to the Python interpreter using File > Settings > Project Interpreter, by simply pointing to "python.exe"

For PyQt4, I can see the folder in

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

But which file do I actually "point to"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I solved this for Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.4.4:

```
File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter > <Python version>
```

Double-click `setup tools`

In `Search`, type `PyQt4`

In left pane, don't select `PyQT4`. This will give the error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4
```

Instead, select `PyQt4_windows_whl`. For me, this was successful.

Test in editor by typing:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

As soon as I typed

```
from P
```

`PyQt4` appeared in the dropdown.

As soon as I typed

```
from PyQt4 import Q
```

`QtGui` appeared in the dropdown.

I'm no expert, so I don't know  if these tests are conclusive.

Comment: I was getting similar 'unresolved' error when I tried importing the PyQt4 for QtCore and QtGui. So I followed the suggestion given above by @OldGrantonian. After installing 'PyQt4_windows_whl' the error at import lines was resolved but now the error propagated to the elements of QtCore and QtGui that I used later. To tackle this I installed "PyQt4Enhanced" and all errors were cleared.

PS - I too faced the same {Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4} issue when I tried installing PyQt4 package.

Comment: When I tried this, pycharm told me to run 'pip install pyqt4_windows_whl' from the command line, which did seem to work

Comment: Im on Ubuntu and installed the enhanced version but the error still came up with No Module Named PyQt4!